# Why is there blank text appearing in the toast output when i have a string?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, toast

As far as i know this will store the user and pass in the variables i made.Then get the text and convert it to a string.Now if that is happening how come only a blank bubble appears when i call it?

```
package com.set.ultimax.login;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button logIn;
    EditText user;
    EditText pass;

    logIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    final String userValue = user.getText().toString();
    final String passValue = pass.getText().toString();

    logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            Toast.makeText(Main.this,userValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(Main.this,passValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: please accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the text from the `EditText`s at the time you click the button, instead of getting it on `onCreate`.

Try this:

```java
logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click

        final String userValue = user.getText().toString();
        final String passValue = pass.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(Main.this,userValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(Main.this,passValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't take values in onCreate, do it in the listener and don't show two toasts consecutively at they will overlap. Something like this:

```
logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
        EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        String userValue = user.getText().toString();
        String passValue = pass.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(Main.this,"User: " + userValue + " Pass: " + passValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```